# match a list of words in a line using regex in python

Tags: python

I am looking for an expression to match strings against a list of words like `["xxx", "yyy", "zzz"]`. The strings need to contain all three words but they do not need to be in the same order.

E.g., the following strings should be matched:

```
'"yyy" string of words and than “zzz" string of words “xxx"'
```

or

```
'string of words “yyy””xxx””zzz” string of words'
```

Comment: Are repetitions allowed (i. e. can `xxx` occur more than once)?

Comment: The repetitions are allowed but all three words should occur at least once.

Answer (score 6):

Simple string operation:

```
mywords = ("xxx", "yyy", "zzz")
all(x in mystring for x in mywords)
```

If word boundaries are relevant (i. e. you want to match `zzz` but not `Ozzzy`):

```
import re
all(re.search(r"\b" + re.escape(word) + r"\b", mystring) for word in mywords)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `all` and `re.search` for finding matches.

```
>>> words = ('xxx', 'yyy' ,'zzz')
>>> text = "sdfjhgdsf zzz sdfkjsldjfds yyy dfgdfgfd xxx"
>>> all([re.search(w, text) for w in words])
True
```