# Find an element of list (months) in a text with findall

Tags: python, regex, findall

I have a text in which for each line are present several dates, eg: `August 30, 1981` or `Nov 11, 1988`, and I would like to find them.
So far I've made a line for each month like this:

```
df['text'].str.findall(r'(Jan[a-z]*)(\s\d?\d)[,](\s\d\d\d\d)')
```

Instead of make several lines of code one for each month, I thought that iterate over a list containing the month would be more elegant:

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October','November', 'December', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

and then with a single line of code find them all.
Is it possible a solution like the one proposed in this post [match a list of words in a line using regex in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430188/match-a-list-of-words-in-a-line-using-regex-in-python), but with findall instead?
I thought something like:

```
df['text'].str.findall(re.escape(month) + r' (\s\d?\d)[,](\s\d\d\d\d)'), for month in months)
```

but apparently it is not correct.

Some lines of the text:

```
last day of the championship July 28, 1983
Mar 11, 1990 record of the first division
April 27, 1982 record of played matches
```

The output I would like is:

```
[(July,  28,  1983)]
[(Mar,  11,  1990)]
[(April,  27,  1092)]
```

Comment: Could you upload some sample data - that would make it easier to help out with the problem.

Comment: @Philip updated with some examples

Comment: Given your data's format, why not just parse out the first 3 fields? No search required if it's a fixed format.

Comment: @AIG this is just an example of the lines, i can also find them in the middle of the text. I will modify one line of the example

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do it:

```
pattern = '(?:{})'.format('|'.join(months)) + '\s[\d]{1,2},\s[\d]{4}'
df['text'].str.findall(pattern)
```

Or to match your desired output:

```
pattern = '((?:{}))'.format('|'.join(months)) + '(\s[\d]{1,2}),(\s[\d]{4})'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following expressing, that I've tested on your sample data.

```
[tuple(df['text'].str.re.findall("(\w+ \d+.+\d)")[0].replace(",","").split())]
```

This will leave you with

```
[('July', '28', '1983')]
```

Using this, you do not need your months list